# Program Not Returning Any Value

Tags: android, web-services, return

I am new to android programming. Just wrote this code to convert kg's to grams through a web service. The program takes input from a user and returns the value in textbox but sadly I am not getting back any value. Please help.

```
package com.example.Passing;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


public class PassingActivity extends Activity
{
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";
private final String URL = "http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertWeight.asmx";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConvertWeight";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "ConvertWeight";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button   mButton;
EditText mEdit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(

            new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    String weight = mEdit.getText().toString();

                    String fromUnit = "Kilograms";
                    String toUnit = "Grams";

                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 


                    PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();
                    weightProp.setName("Weight");
                    weightProp.setValue(weight);
                    weightProp.setType(double.class);
                    request.addProperty(weightProp);            

                    PropertyInfo fromProp =new PropertyInfo();
                    fromProp.setName("FromUnit");
                    fromProp.setValue(fromUnit);
                    fromProp.setType(String.class);
                    request.addProperty(fromProp);

                    PropertyInfo toProp =new PropertyInfo();
                    toProp.setName("ToUnit");
                    toProp.setValue(toUnit);
                    toProp.setType(String.class);
                    request.addProperty(toProp);


                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                    try 
                    {
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                        Log.i("myApp", response.toString());

                        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit);
                        et.setText("equal"+response.toString());


                        /*  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.setText(weight+" "+fromUnit+" equal "+response.toString()+ " "+toUnit);
                        setContentView(tv);*/

                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    }}
```

The main.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText 
    android:layout_margin="20dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minLines="15"
    android:maxLines="15"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:editable="false"
    android:id="@+id/my_edit"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Convert" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoapPrimitive doesn't always work fine. Try changing how you get the response for something like this: `SoapObject result_xml = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;`

instead of `SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();`

**Edit:**
This is the code I used and worked perfectly (I used a `Fragment` but you can do the same in an `Activity`) but remember that any lenght operations (like internet since they can cause time outs or lags in network wich take more than 5s) **must** be done in a thread if you dont want to have unwanted side effects like the famous ANRs.

```
    public class TestFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";
    private final String URL = "http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertWeight.asmx";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConvertWeight";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "ConvertWeight";

    private EditText textToConvert;
    private String weight;
    private Button send;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        final View view = getView();
        textToConvert = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ammount);
        send = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        send.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate( R.layout.main, container, false );
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            weight = textToConvert.getText().toString();
            new AsyncSendData().execute();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }


    public class AsyncSendData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String fromUnit = "Kilograms";
            String toUnit = "Grams";

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
            PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();
            weightProp.setName("Weight");
            weightProp.setValue(weight);
            weightProp.setType(double.class);
            request.addProperty(weightProp);            

            PropertyInfo fromProp =new PropertyInfo();
            fromProp.setName("FromUnit");
            fromProp.setValue(fromUnit);
            fromProp.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(fromProp);

            PropertyInfo toProp =new PropertyInfo();
            toProp.setName("ToUnit");
            toProp.setValue(toUnit);
            toProp.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(toProp);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try 
            {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapObject result_xml = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                Log.e("myApp", result_xml.toString());
            } 
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the layout I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="From" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ammount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:inputType="number">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

so at the post execute method you can update your view...

Comment: i followed as u suggested but it still doesnt work.. i click the button but dont get anything in return.. is the code correct? coz i cant find any error !!

Comment: well I tried the code and got the response with good data. Perhaps you wrote something wrong.

Comment: yeah the code works fine when u initialize the weight as a default value.. i am trying to get the value from user in a text box and then convert it.. thats the issue when it is not returning the value.. the code i posted is for the same purpose only !!

Comment: I juste edited the code so you can receive the input from an EditText but yet again the code works.

Comment: just one error
'The method getView() is undefined for the type TestFragment'

what shud i do about this ?

Comment: the method getView() only works when you are calling the view from outside an activity in my case in a Fragment. So if you have Fragment then you shoulndn't have any problem.
If you are doing this from an Activity then you don't need that line and you just call your widgets normally with the findViewById method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the kSoap lib that you are using.
However, you are calling a web service which takes some time to process and then trying to get the return value immediately. This looks problematic. The way this usually works is that you call you web service and then there will be some called back that is to be executed once your service returns with your data.